# installation using wubi shows errors please help

Tags: wubi, system-installation

i got these errors while attempting installation at windows XP using wubi 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=X2QRhGcb

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=167ZPnwV

Comment: please help !!!

Comment: also check http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=167ZPnwV

Comment: How about you download the image separately since your internet seems unstable. Also, you should use an updated version of Wubi.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong version of `wubi.exe`. Doesn't match the ISO you have on `G:`. Get the latest `wubi.exe` where you downloaded the ISO.

If you want to install from a 32-bit ISO on a PC with 64-bit architecture (which it appears you are doing), then run with the `--32bit` command line option e.g. `wubi.exe --32bit`. Also, don't put the ISO in the root of the drive, because Wubi will copy the partition instead of just the ISO (weird one).

If you install from the diskimage (without the ISO) then just use the latest version of `wubi.exe`.

**tldr;**

To install with ISO:

1. Download latest verstion of Ubuntu ISO and `wubi.exe` from the same place, and store in same folder (not root of drive). Run with `--32bit` option if you want to install 32 bit version
2. Download latest version of `wubi.exe` and run standalone to install from diskimage (remove any existing ISOs you have from roots of drives or local directory).

Comment: it appears that my wubi.exe is different. i re did the entire process with th wubi that came with my ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso and got this error http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tbBWfZ8i

Comment: more trials also resulted into similar errors
downloaded 64bit ubuntu precise pangolin and achieved nothing but similar errors http://upaste.me/r/2efe9566282bc3b2

Comment: @user230513 where did you get the `wubi.exe`? It's the wrong version: `01-02 16:22 INFO   root: === wubi 12.04.1 rev273 ===` or you pasted the wrong logfile.